# Firebase Could Functions body is empty when called from Ract App

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, axios, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating Nextjs React application  with firebase Cloud functions.

The problem I have encountered is when I make request using Axios from the app

```
  await Axios(
    {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://#################.cloudfunctions.net/contactUs',
      data: data,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
  );
```

in the cloud function

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
exports.contactUs = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {}
```

`request.body` is always empty object. 
and `request.rawBody === undefined`

It works fine when I make the request using Postman.

Comment: Have you made sure the data in your variable `data` is enumerable? An easy way to test this is to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`. You also shouldn't need to specify the content type as Axios will handle `data` as JSON by default for you.

Comment: data is a simple 3 property object
{"email":"dddd@gmail.com","message":"gggg","name":"aaaa"} 
Added headers out of desperation

Comment: Your function seems incomplete. Could you edit the question to show the all of the missing data?  We need to be able to see the value of `data` in addition to the code inside the function that shows how you're examining the request.  Please don't omit any details.  Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve